# How to write a Jenkins Cron with multiple parameters

Tags: jenkins, cron

I have an issue and can't seem to find results or information online.

Let's say I have a software for generating descriptions (and optional images) for dogs. The Jenkins pipeline has parameters such as name, type, a checkbox for generating an image, etc.

When I manually run the software on "build with parameters", I can fill in the boxes as so:

```
dog_type
```

Is the breed of dog.

```
dog_name
```

Name of the dog.

```
generate_image
```

is a checkbox that I click if I want an image for the dog to generate.

I want to set up a weekly run to generate a dog and picture. How would I write it to have multiple parameters?

I've tried this:

```
H 0 * * 1 dog_type=poodle dog_name=Molly generate_image=True
```

Which is supposed to run weekly, generating a picture of a poodle named Molly.

But that didn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/). Example Pipeline below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
      string(name: 'PLANET', defaultValue: 'Earth', description: 'Which planet are we on?')
      string(name: 'GREETING', defaultValue: 'Hello', description: 'How shall we greet?')
    }
    triggers {
        parameterizedCron('''
            # leave spaces where you want them around the parameters. They'll be trimmed.
            # we let the build run with the default name
            */2 * * * * %GREETING=Hola;PLANET=Pluto
            */3 * * * * %PLANET=Mars
        ''')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "${params.GREETING} ${params.PLANET}"
                script { currentBuild.description = "${params.GREETING} ${params.PLANET}" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```